# ¿Cómo puedo tener el dia de la semana en mariadb?

Tags: sql, mariadb

¿Cómo puedo tener el día de la semana en mariadb? osea lunes es 1 martes es 2 y miércoles es 3?

Estaba intentando de esta manera pero no me funciono:

```
select datepart(dw,'2022-06-30') as dia_de_la_semana from citas;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la documentación, puedes usar [`dayofweek()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dayofweek/), por ejemplo:

```
select dayofweek('2022-06-30') as dia_de_la_semana from citas;
```

Ten en cuenta, que esta función sigue el estándar ODBC dónde 1 = Domingo, 2 = Lunes, ..., 7 = sábado. Si quieres que lunes sea 1:

```
select case when dayofweek('2022-06-30') = 1 
           then 7
           else dayofweek('2022-06-30') - 1
       end as dia_de_la_semana 
       from citas;
```

O bien usar [`weekday()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/weekday/) dónde el retorno es 0 = Lunes, ..., 6 domingo

```
select weekday('2022-06-30') + 1 as dia_de_la_semana from citas;
```

Comment: Gracias me funciono correctamente